# prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF)

Tags: asp.net, csrf

How can we prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks in ASP.Net webForm. i want to secure some of pages in website and also how can we prevent if we received URL in the Email, from the attacker to perform CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

You can take some extra precautions.

1. First connect **your user** authentication and actions, **with the IP and the browser information's**.  So on each action, also verify that the actions are done from the user that have all that criteria.
2. **encrypt some critical data/variables** (that CSRF have to change) - and not let the variables only pass from SSL but plain text -
3. always use encrypted SSL cookies. `requireSSL=true.`
4. Do not allow cross app redirects `enableCrossAppRedirects=false`
5. Use one database table, **to connect each authentication cookie with user actions** like the log-out, so you know that the cookie is (maybe ?) logged out, or inactive, or something - even if its valid.
6. Block in advanced blocked ips that they have found that attacks. 
   http://www.phoenixlabs.org/pg2/